# How to report a bug to tmpfs?

Tags: mount, tmpfs

I would like to propose a new feature to tmpfs and discuss it. Where should I do this? I guess I can create a ticket in Linux Kernel's bugzilla but not sure if they "own" the tmpfs because it's also used in FreeBSD and other systems.
The similar think I would like to propose to mount `bind` command and as I understand it completely belongs to the mount/libmount so I should create a ticket there.
Can you point me how to make it properly.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear what the scope of your feature is, but as far as the Linux kernel is concerned, it does own its own implementation of `tmpfs`, and the contact information given in [`MAINTAINERS`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/MAINTAINERS) is

```
TMPFS (SHMEM FILESYSTEM)
M:      Hugh Dickins <hughd@google.com>
L:      linux-mm@kvack.org
S:      Maintained
F:      include/linux/shmem_fs.h
F:      mm/shmem.c
```

I would therefore suggest contacting the mailing list, linux-mm@kvack.org.